# C Language Program Dynamic Table with use of poionters

Tags: c

I wrote this program under 64bit win7 in C with DevC 
and it stacks all the time , when it began it makes the first table and when trying to double the table it stack ,someone told me about realloc but i dont know the use of it if somenone can help i apretiate . thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
system("COLOR A");  
srand(time(NULL));  
int a,b,c,i,j;
int *p,*r;  
int k;

printf("Dwse ari8mo grammwn pinaka : ");
scanf("%d",&a);       /*scanf for x,y of table */
printf("\n\n\n");
printf("Dwse ari8mo sthlwn pinaka : ");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("\n");

int pinak[a][b];  /*table declare*/

for (i=0;i<a;i++) /* creation and filling of table pinak[a][b]*/ {
    for (j=0;j<b;j++){
        pinak[i][j]=(rand()%(500-1))+1;  /*Fillinig the table  */
       } 
    }   

  /*printing the table*/

for (i=0;i<a;i++){
     for (k=0;k<((b+1)*2);k++){
          printf("---");    
     }  
     printf("\n");

     for (j=0;j<b;j++){                  
       printf("|%4d |",pinak[i][j]);                    
     }      
       printf("\n");        
    }       
for (k=0;k<(b+1)*2;k++){
          printf("---");    
}

p=&a;  /*pointer ffor double the table dynamic */
r=&b;

printf("H dieu8insi mnhmhs A einai : %d kai i 8esh b einai : %d",*p,*r);

printf("\n");
printf("\n");

*p=(*p)*2;  /* doubling the x,y of table */
*r=(*r)*2;

    /* Create and fill the new table */ 

for (i=0;i<a;i++){
      for (k=0;k<((b+1)*2);k++){
          printf("---");    
       }  
      printf("\n");
     for (j=0;j<b;j++){          
       if(i<(a/2) && j<(b/2)){           
           printf("|%4d |",pinak[i][j]);                      
        }
       else{
         pinak[i][j]=(rand()%(500-1))+1;
         printf("|%4d |",pinak[i][j]);                              
       }                          
      }                                         
      printf("\n");     
 }      
for (k=0;k<(b+1)*2;k++){
          printf("---");    
}   
system("PAUSE");    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite sample with malloc and realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE(n) do { int num = n; while(num--){ putchar('-'); } putchar('\n'); }while(0)

int main(void){
    system("COLOR A");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int a, b;
    int **pinak;
    int i, j;

    printf("input a and b for pinak[a][b] : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    /* creation and filling of table pinak[a][b] */
    pinak = malloc(a * sizeof(*pinak));//malloc(a * sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
        pinak[i] = malloc(b * sizeof(*pinak[0]));//malloc(b * sizeof(int);
        for(j = 0; j < b; j++){
            pinak[i][j] = (rand()%(500-1))+1;/*Fillinig the table  */
        } 
    }

    /*printing the table*/
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
        LINE(b * 6 + 1);
        for(j=0;j<b;j++){
            printf("|%4d ", pinak[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
    LINE(b * 6 + 1);

    int a2 = a*2, b2 = b*2;//expand width and height
    pinak = realloc(pinak, a2 * sizeof(*pinak));
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        pinak[i] = realloc(pinak[i], b2 * sizeof(*pinak[0]));
        for(j = b; j < b2; j++){
            pinak[i][j]=(rand()%(500-1))+1;
        } 
    }
    for(i = a; i < a2; i++) {
        pinak[i] = malloc(b2 * sizeof(*pinak[0]));
        for(j = 0; j < b2; j++){
            pinak[i][j] = (rand()%(500-1))+1;
        } 
    }

    /*printing the table*/
    for(i = 0; i < a2; i++){
        LINE(b2 * 6 + 1);
        for(j = 0; j < b2; j++){
            printf("|%4d ", pinak[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
    LINE(b2 * 6 + 1);

    //release
    for(i = 0; i < a2; i++)
        free(pinak[i]);
    free(pinak);

    system("PAUSE");
    system("COLOR 7");
    return 0;
}
```